# Separate query in single var and execute it using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I have currently working on `perl script`.

```
Select Column1,Column2,Column3.. from table.
```

This query contain some part in `$cmd="Select Column1 ";`
and other `$cmd1=",Column2,Column3 from table";  // This is dynamic part, so split query in two different variable.`
After this execute whole query.

How to do this query splitting part.?

Comment: Whats wrong with just concatenating the two parts, and then run the concatenation?

Comment: You need to show more of your code. It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Your input !
my $cmd  = "Select Column1 "; 
my $cmd1 = ",Column2,Column3 from table";

# I am wondering why you have your query like this ...
# but anyway, lets assume there's a reason behind this!

my $dbh = 
    DBI->connect(
        'DBI:mysql:databasename;host=db.example.com', # TODO Change this
        'username',                                   # TODO change this
        'password',                                   # TODO change this
        { RaiseError => 1 }
    ) or die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $cmd . $cmd1 );

$sth->execute();

my @row;
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    print "@row\n";
}
```